# How to specify Routing key dynamically in Spring xd for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I am trying to set routingkey value of RabbitMQ Sink in SpringXD using
    '{$payload.routingkey'}

As payload carries  the entire message ,My message is a json
    {"routingkey":"Disney","text":"DisneyTweet"}

But it gives error complaining

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'payload.routingKey' in string value "${payload.routingKey}"
```

How can i set Routingkey from a value that is in my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `$`

```
--routingKey='payload.routingkey'"
```

Which uses the SpEL Json property accessor.

Or you can use the `jsonPath` SpEL function:

```
--routingKey='#jsonPath(payload, \"$.routingkey\")'"
```